# Adding whitespace at bottom of HTML page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website where I have both the title bar and the page footer in fixed positions, i.e. title bar always top and footer always bottom.

This has created issue in that I need to push the content on the page upwards so that the page footer will not overlap the content. 
I need to add some space to the bottom of the content so that the overlap doesn't occur when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page. 
I have tried to add a `margin-bottom` css property to the bottom most DIV so that there should be some space added to the bottom of the page, this worked for the top most DIV using a `margin-top` css property but not for the bottom.

This is the main structure to my website, without content:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="CONTAINER">
        <div class="PAGENAVBAR">
        </div>
        <div class='CATEGORYNAVBAR'>
        </div>
        <div class='PAGE_CONTENT'>      
            <div class="LEFTCONTAINER">
            </div>

            <div class="RIGHTCONTAINER">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="PAGEFOOTER">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can someone please suggest a method to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've found this to be effective:

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I've recently seen this pop up on my feed and looking back from my naive days, I believe using padding-bottom is the better option

Comment: but this adds space, even when there already is white space. how can i have it only when there is none.

Comment: True, I don't know of a way to selectively add whitespace using CSS only when whitespace isn't there from something else. If I were in your situation, I'd look into ways of eliminating this other source of whitespace. I get super annoyed when people respond "don't do that" to my question, though, so one possibility is to use Javascript to apply this rule selectively after examining if it already has whitespce. I think that's probably possible, although you'd have to dig around to figure out exactly how.

Answer (score 9):

margin-bottom moves the whole element, try padding-bottom instead.

Comment: Could you explain the diff between margin- and padding-bottom. They seem similar to me?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to understand the difference is to inspect some element on a page and look at the box model layout. For example, I'm on Firefox and I did this:
1. Right click on your comment and choose inspect
2. Select the parent div with the class comment-text
3. Choose the layout tab in the right pane
4. Scroll down to the bottom and look at the Box Model

Answer (score 2):

adding padding-bottom to the last element should do this, or you could add padding-bottom to the container element, just remember that this will be added to the height if you have it set in your css

Comment: I've tried adding the padding to the container element but for some reason it had no effect at all, not sure why though

Comment: As comment nine years after you answered I'd like to add that your answer makes more sense as the better rated "add padding-bottom to body". In vertical centered elements e.g. with css grid in a container you will have space to the bottom of the screen with padding-bottom on an inside element on pages which don't fit on some screen, while body padding-bottom will be "centered out" and the last element will stick at the browsers bottom.

Answer (score 1):

use paragraph to do this. [html paragraph](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I did try this tactic before but I left the text blank, as soon as I added some characters into the <p> field, the effect I wanted was achieved.

Comment: While this is *a* way to fix this issue, this is not the right way. See @pjmil116's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'padding-bottom' instead. The behaviour of this is more consistent across different browsers than 'margin-bottom'.

But be aware this will add to the overall height of the element in question, if you're using this in any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give `PAGE_CONTENT` a `margin-bottom`; you may need to also give it `overflow:hidden` if your `LEFTCONTAINER` and `RIGHT_CONTAINER` are floated.

Answer (score 0):

In css give margin-bottom attribute to the container class.

```
.container{
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
```